# Jquery: how to check if clicked on some element in the if condition

Tags: jquery

My problem is if click on this $("ul li ul li"),  $("ul li") also gets the event click.

If I click on this $("ul li ul li"), I dont want any action defined for click on  $("ul li") to happen.

```
        <script>
        $(function(){
              $("ul li ul").css("display", "none");
              $("ul li ul li ul").css("display", "none");

          $("ul li ul li").on("click", function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                   e.stopPropagation();

            var x=$(this).find("ul").css("display");
               if(x=="none"){
                 alert("down");
                 $(this).find("ul").css("display", "block");
                 e.stopPropagation();
             return false;
              }

              if(x=="block" || x=="inline"){
                 alert("down else");
                 $(this).find("ul").css("display", "none");
                 return false;
              }

           });

           $("ul li").on("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

            var x=$(this).find("ul").css("display");
               if(x=="none" ){
                alert("up");    
                 $("ul li ul").css("display", "none");
                 $("ul li ul li ul").css("display", "none");
                $(this).find("ul").css("display", "block");
                $(this).find("ul li ul").css("display", "none");
                return false;

              }

              if(x=="block" || x=="inline"){
                alert("up else");   
                 $(this).find("ul").css("display", "none");
                 return false;
              }

           });


        });
        </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @guradio I used it but still , down and upelse are alerted when I click on $("ul li ul li")

Comment: PS: Why not use .show() and .hide()

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your question, please say if so. I would give the parent ul of the children li's you want the click binded to an id, and target its direct descendant li's specifically as follows:

Jquery:

```
$("#uniqueid > li").on("click", function(e) {
```

Html:

```
<ul id="uniqueid">
```